# Creating an application launcher in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm working on creating a small process manager in C#. The idea is to create a small application that allows me to open and close other executable files with preset arguments and also track the time each one was open. I'm wrapping my own emulator manager, for context.

Is `Process.Start` the right way to go? Are there any caveats in this method, specially related to CPU and ownership? What about current directory, access, etc?

I'm using .NET Core!

Comment: What are you looking for that is outside of what is already available in say something like a scheduled task or windows service?

Comment: I'm doing my own emulator manager, so i can easily see the games i'm used to play. I'm also going to use it to learn more about UI's in C#, by adding a game selector, search, etc. It's a hobby project. I also want to keep stats on what i've been playing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using the `Process` class, it's meant for executing EXEs.

Example:

```
Process process = new Process();

try
{
    process.StartInfo.FileInfo = "C:\\MyProgram.exe";
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.Exited += (sender, e) => { /* Code executed on process exit */ };
    process.Start();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: Can i listen to any event that tells me when the process died?

Comment: @vinnylinux You can use `process.HasExited' to check that process, or `process.WaitForExit()' if you want to suspend the program until it exits. Or I would personally recommend subscribing to the exit event: `process.EnableRaisingEvents = true; process.Exited += (sender, e) = { /* code */ };`

Comment: according to the Documentation there is an Exited event ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx ), that Occurs when a process exits.